# Firebase Cloud Messaging: ı cant upload APNs authentication key

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

ı have APNs authentication key but ıcan upload firebase because  in settings > cloud messaging > iOS app configuration is not active
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTTOT.png)